# Catching 403 error from s3 presigned url timeout in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, try-catch, pre-signed-url

I'm getting a presigned url from an s3 bucket with a timeout of 15 mins(I know this can be increased but i want to avoid a long expiry for security reasons).

After 15 mins when i try and use this url i get a 403 error in my react app console.

I can not catch this error in the usual way because I'm not actually calling a function to get this error, it comes from aws when the url has timed out.

I would like to call my function that gets the signed url as soon as i get this 403 error so that it updates without the users knowing, but I have no way of catching it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

I could use a setTimeout function to get another signed url after 15 minutes but would like to know if there is a better way of handling this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks specifics, so I'm making some assumptions here.

You should do it the other way around. Instead of getting the signed URL in advance and wait for the user to do something to use it (for example, clicking on a button), only generate the signed URL when the user clicked on the button. This way you don't need to worry about expiration as the URL is used seconds after it is signed.

For example, if you want to open a file when the user clicked on a button, use:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // get the signed URL
    const response = await fetch("<backend url>");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    const url = await response.text();
    // use the URL
    window.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I do get the url only when required but this issue happens when the user has been inactive for over 15 minutes and tries to use it again i get the timeout error.

Comment: In that case you are not getting the url when required:) When the user clicks on a button or does the thing that requires the url *then* get the signed url. If you can't detect a click or the user action, you can make a HTTP redirect to the signed url from your backend.